# What's a function in which y doesn't depend on x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

The question seems odd to me but it was asked to me as a job interview question. Specifically I was first asked, "Does y always depend on x"? The follow up question was can I think of a function in which y doesn't depend on x.

Comment: A constant function?

Comment: Constant???????

Comment: y =y(t) depends on t not x

Comment: What type of job?

Comment: Any function $f(x, y) $ on $[a, b] \times [c, d] $.

Comment: $y=y(t)$, $y=y(p)$ ...

Comment: Without knowing the context it is impossible to answer the question except by guessing.

Comment: Default is that "$y=f(x)$" is meant (I would always assume that if no other context is given). In this case, the constant functions are clearly the counterexamples. In fact, whatever is meant, we can use constant functions as a counterexample.

Comment: You could have pulled a Neo and said, "Sure, the empty function. There is no $x$."  What type of job was it for?